# Create models dynamically in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using mongo and sails.js. My application allows the user to create a new collection in the mongodb. Since this collection is being created by the user there is no sails model in the models folder therefore I cannot query the new collection (create,update,delete) etc.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I was looking into the Model.native() built in function but there is no model generated when a user creates a new collection so that won't work.

Comment: You cant do that. Even if you generate new Model you need to reboot server to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

That depends in what you want: creating a new model or just a collection.

- **Model**

If you want to **generate a new model** and access with GET, POST, etc.. like when you create a new API with:

> sails generate api foo

**you need** to run the command and then **restart server**, because server needs to map models with db collections.

- **Collection**

If you want to create a collection consider that you won't be able to access this collection via GET, POST because it's not a model.

MongoDB **does not create a database or collection until the first document** is inserted. So, if you just want to **create a new collection** in mongoDB you can **run your own script** to do it.

This is basically how it works and is by design. When you insert some data the database and collection will be created.

For example you can run a **python script** with [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
import testdata
from pprint import pprint

client = MongoClient()
db     = client.test['collectionDummy']

import datetime

class Temp(testdata.DictFactory):
    id        = testdata.CountingFactory(10)
    number    = testdata.CountingFactory(10)
    address   = testdata.FakeDataFactory('address')
    firstName = testdata.FakeDataFactory('firstName')

for document in Temp().generate(2):
    result = db.insert_one(document)
```